# When reconnect to Colaboratory, my computer crashed

Tags: google-colaboratory

I tried to run my deep learning code on Colaboratory, but every time I run to 26% this progress, it automatically disconnects, and the computer freezes when I reconnect to the server. My training loop is shown below：

```
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image
dev_gen_costs = []
config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'gpu':0})
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config = config)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for iteration in tqdm_notebook(range(ITERS), desc='generate and discriminate'):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    start_time = time.time()
    num = iteration%(train_vis.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE)
    data_IR = train_ir[num*BATCH_SIZE:(num+1)*BATCH_SIZE,:,:]
    data_VI = train_vis[num*BATCH_SIZE:(num+1)*BATCH_SIZE,:,:]
    data_IR = np.expand_dims(data_IR,axis = -1)
    data_VI = np.expand_dims(data_VI,axis = -1)
    feed_dict={real_data1_int:data_IR, real_data2_int:data_VI}
    # Train generator
    _ = sess.run([gen_train_op],feed_dict)
    # Train critic
    for i in range(CRITIC_ITERS):
        _costs, _ = sess.run([[disc_cost ,gen_cost],disc_train_op] ,feed_dict)
        dev_gen_costs.append(_costs)#loss
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash is due to some errors in the code you are running.

Comment: In fact, the same code runs on my computer without any problems, so can you tell me where my code went wrong?

Comment: There are lot of things to check when moving to colab. Tensorflow version, Dependency modules, Paths given in the code. Run step by step and see where exactly the problem is occuring. use try except to catch errors, so that it won't crash the notebook